# Flexbox почему появляется горизонтальная прокрутка?

Tags: html, css, css3

Почему блоки `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` не растягиваются вниз по высоте так чтобы
не было горизонтальной прокрутки на ширине экрана от `630px` до `830px`, ведь у блоков нет фиксированный ширины, что им может мешать растягиваться?

пример на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Achilles21/pen/RxQGve)

[image: Flexbox почему появляется горизонтальная прокрутка?[1]]

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css);

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  background: #3cb371;
/*  font-size: 14px;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;*/
min-width: 300px;
/*overflow-x: hidden;*/
overflow-y: scroll;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
/*
body {
color: #666;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.4;
}
*/

article {
/*text-decoration: none;*/
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

div, h2, p, figure {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.header {
color: white;
padding: 40px 0 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.header h2 a {
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.header h2 a:hover {
border-bottom-color: white;
opacity: 1;
}

.main-21 {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1040px;
padding: 10px;
}

.column {
flex: 1;
flex-direction: column;
}

.article {
background: white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
color: #666;
display: flex;
/*Aligns all blocks at the same height*/
/*flex: 1;*/   
flex-direction: column;
flex-basis: auto;
margin: 10px;
}

.article:hover,
.article:focus {
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
color: #444;
}

.article-image {
background: #eee;
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
/*padding-top: 75%;*/
}

.article-image img {
display: block;
/*height: 100%;*/
width: 100%;
/*left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;*/
}

/*.article-image.is-3by2 {
padding-top: 66.6666%;
}

.article-image.is-16by9 {
padding-top: 56.25%;
}*/

.article-body {
display: flex;
flex: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 20px;
}

.article-title {
color: #333;
flex-shrink: 0;
font-size: 1.4em;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 1.2;
}

.article-content {
flex: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.article-info {
display: flex;
font-size: 0.85em;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-top: 10px;
}

/*@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {*/
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .columns,
  .column {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .first-article {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .first-article .article-body {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .first-article .article-image {
    /*height: 300px;*/
    /*order: 2;*/
    padding-top: 0;
    /*width: 400px;*/
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .main-column {
    /*flex: 3;*/
    flex: 1;
  }

  .nested-column {
    flex: 2;
  }
}

/**/
main .article-image h2{
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main columns">
  <section class="column main-column">

   <article class="article first-article" href="#">
    <figure class="article-image is-4by3">
      <h2>Toronto Concert Band – 2017 Fall Concert</h2>
      <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
      <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/winds-of-change.png" alt="">
    </figure>
  </article>
  <div class="columns">
   <div class="column">
    <article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F366920122F2310469983842F12Foriginal.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title">
          Jeremy Olander at City At Night
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Friday Nov.17, Cityscape Sessions and City At Night proudly present:&nbsp; JEREMY OLANDER [Vivrant, Bedr</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F361224882F1518810489042F12Foriginal.png" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title">
          Walker &amp; Royce Self Help Tour at Sunday Sessions
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Sunday Sessions – November 12, 2017 Dirtybird Presents: Walker &amp; Royce (Brooklyn, NY) </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div></div>
  <article class="article first-article" href="#">
    <figure class="article-image is-4by3">
      <h2>2017 Creative Futures Expo Presented by Applied Arts</h2>
      <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
      <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https-2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F345884992F1570794900392F12Foriginal.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </article>
  <div class="columns">
   <div class="column">
    <article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F271412772F1762268901392F12Foriginal.png" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title">
          SAVE the DATE – Mercury Lounge is turning 21 years old
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Mercury Lounge is Turning 21 years old We will be celebrating this milestone throught the entire mon</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F356429922F1454087557902F12Foriginal.png" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title">
          Monkey Rock Music Halloween Party and Fundraiser
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Monkey Rock Music is excited to present our annual Halloween Party and Fundraiser! As always, a port</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div></div></section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column"><article class="article" href="#">
        <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
          <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
          <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F362864052F2003438030152F12Foriginal.jpg" alt="">
        </figure>
        <div class="article-body">
          <h2 class="article-title  7 | 1">
            Deep Therapy : Halloween in a dfsdf  (Блок 1)
          </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Ottawa’s biggest LGBTQ seasonal party is back for Halloween! GET YOUR TICKET EARLY & SAVE:www.sashay.eventbrite.caFri Oct. 27 | Barrymores | 10:30pmFeaturing DJ/Producer: DJ MARK FALCO (To  Ottawa’s biggest LGBTQ seasonal party is back for Halloween! GET YOUR TICKET EARLY & SAVE:www.sashay.eventbrite.caFri Oct. 27 | Barrymores | 10:30pmFeaturing DJ/Producer: DJ MARK FALCO (To</p>
        </div>
      </article><article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->

        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F344084352F1761370899072F12Foriginal.jpg" alt="">

      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title  8 | 0">
          11th Annual Great Pumpkin Charity Ball (Блок 2)
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> 11th Annual Great Pumpkin Charity BallOttawa’s Biggest &amp; Best Annual Halloween eventSaturday, October 28, 2017St. Brigid’s Haunted Castle, 310 St. Patrick’s Street$40 tickets available at:M</p>
      </div>
    </article></div>
    <div class="column"><article class="article" href="#">
      <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
        <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->
        <!-- <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F362864052F2003438030152F12Foriginal.jpg" alt=""> -->
        <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F361056662F1613618451482F12Foriginal.png" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="article-body">
        <h2 class="article-title  7 | 1">
          Deep Therapy : Halloween in a Warehouse (Блок 3)
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Ottawa’s biggest LGBTQ o вав вав вава</p>
      </div>
    </article><article class="article" href="#">
    <figure class="article-image is-16by9">
      <!--<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/image-01-lo.jpg" alt="">-->

      <!-- <img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/https3A2F2Fcdn.evbuc_.com2Fimages2F344084352F1761370899072F12Foriginal.jpg" alt=""> -->
<img src="http://bigplansfortheweekend.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ottawauppercanadavillagepumpkinpumpkinferno-1444928529c8pl4.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
    <div class="article-body">
      <h2 class="article-title  8 | 0">
        11th Annual dfdfdf dfdf dfsdfsdf (Блок 4)
      </h2>
        <p class="article-content"> Ottawa’s biggest LGBTQ seasonal party is back for Halloween! GET YOUR TICKET EARLY & SAVE:www.sashay.eventbrite.caFri Oct. 27 | Barrymores | 10:30pmFeaturing DJ/Producer: DJ MARK FALCO (To </p>
    </div>
  </article></div>
</div>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: блоки ужимаются до размера самого длинного слова. В ваших блоках есть длинные ссылки без пробелов. Испотзуйте     word-break: break-word;

Comment: спасибо,ваш совет помог решить проблему

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в медиа-запрос (min-width: 700px) flex-wrap: wrap, должно помочь